# Is it possible to rename a FTP Folder using FTP commands?

Tags: ftp

Is this possible to rename a folder on a FTP Server using the FTP command ?

I know that there is a Rename command for file renaming, but can I use it for folder's name ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, the same commands (`RNFR`/`RNTO`) are used for renaming directories (folders) as are used for renaming files. Your issue may be that you do not have permissions to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Rename should work:

```
rename <dirname> <newdirname>
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using following code to copy all files and folder after the ftp login function

```
function ftp_sync ($dir) 
{ 
    global $conn_id; 

    if ($dir != ".") 
    { 
        if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir) == false) 
        { 
            echo ("Change Dir Failed: $dir<BR>\r\n"); 
            return; 
        } 
        if (!(is_dir($dir))) 
            mkdir($dir); 
        chdir ($dir); 
    } 

    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); 
    foreach ($contents as $file) 
    { 
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
            continue; 

        if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $file)) 
        { 
            ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
            ftp_sync ($file); 
        } 
        else 
            ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY); 
    } 

    ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
    chdir (".."); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a temporary directory, move all files into it, drop the existing directory, create the directory you want and move all the files into the new directory. Finally, drop the temporary directory.

(Assuming that ftp rename doesn't work because the original folder isn't empty).

Comment: Are you telling me that is impossible to rename a non empty folder on FTP server ?

Comment: No, but I have in my memory that in some cases -- iirc in some ftp server implementations -- you couldn't rename a folder if it wasn't empty. This would be a workaround -- but not a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

This probably depends on the FTP client you are using, and the FTP server you're connecting to.  Can you specify them both?

Comment: I don't use any client. I've to use ftp commands inside my app.

Comment: what server are you testing/using?